# MS Outlook mail not rendering Google API font - Roboto Condensed

Tags: fonts, outlook, webfonts, email-client, google-webfonts

I have an application where its sends and email on daily basis, I am adding below code with my HTML style sheet references:

HTML:

```
              <table width="100%" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" align="left" class="col" style="width:100%;max-width:600px;background-color:#DDDDDD">
                <tr>
                  <td class="col-td" style="padding-left:0px;padding-right:0px">
                        <table width="100%" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" align="left" class="col" style="width:100%;">
                          <tr>
                            <td class="cell-td" style="padding-top: 10px;
                                                       padding-right: 10px;
                                                       padding-bottom: 10px;
                                                       padding-left: 10px">
                                <div style="font-size: 16px; font-family: helvetica,arial,sans-serif; line-height: 1.5; color: initial;"><span style="font-family: 'Roboto Condensed', Arial, sans-serif;">I'm some new text, edit me! OOO</span></div>
                            </td>
                          </tr>
                        </table>
                  </td>
                </tr>
              </table>

              <!--[if mso]></td><![endif]-->
          <!--[if mso]></tr></table><![endif]-->
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table><!--/.container-->
```

I  am unable to see the Roboto Condensed in Email (Outlook, Browser - outlook, gmail), Instead of that its displaying mail clients fall-back font :

I have implemented as per these article, but that's also not working.

1. https://www.postup.com/outlook-fix-for-using-webfonts-in-your-email/
2. https://www.adestra.com/blog/guide-web-fonts-emails/
3. https://mailbakery.com/blog/fonts-html-emails-limitations-solutions-industry-standards/

Answer (score 2):

The majority of email clients don't support every type of HTML content you see on the web client.
For more information, please see the following link:

[Limitations of HTML Email](https://mailchimp.com/help/limitations-of-html-email/)

[The Google Font API and HTML Email](https://www.emailonacid.com/blog/article/industry-news/the_google_font_api_and_html_email/)

You can try other methods to achieve this. For more information, please see the following link:

[All You Need to Know About Web Fonts in Email](https://www.campaignmonitor.com/resources/guides/web-fonts-in-email/#three)

[Can Outlook use a web font in an html email?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17383401/is-there-a-way-to-use-google-web-fonts-in-an-html-email)

Best Regards,

Evan